# Selection and copying of the text inside the table cell is not working in IE11 but working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I was unable to select the text inside the table cell in IE11, but this feature is working in IE8. My requirement is as follows:

I was having the table with many rows with hyperlink option,when I was selecting the particular row of a table it was processing and displaying the data below in the same page, but after that processing is over I must be able to select the data present inside each column of that same row with mouse and copy it somewhere. I have tried many solutions but unable to resolve. Can anyone please help me?

I have tried with the following code inside javascript function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
        $("tr.uiswidget").removeClass("uiswidget");
    }
});
```

There is a class called `uiswidget`, associated with the `tr`, so am removing this `uiswidget` content class,the selection of the text is working but the hyperlink is disabled why because it is removing the entire `uiswidget` content class wherever it found.

```
.uiswidget{"background", "#ffffff url(#{resource['primefaces-tfk:images/ui-bg_flat_100_ffffff_40x100.png']}) 50% 50% repeat-x");
```

the above hyperlink related code is also associated with this .`uiswidget` class so this was also removed, only text selection is happening but hyperlink is not working, please help me

Comment: Please include the code you're using to perform this task so we can help you out.

Comment: @Alfabravo thankyou for earlier response Ill surely add the code